# Deleting audio file from folder

Tags: codeigniter

I'm not sure where the problem lies. But the code won't unlink the file.

$file_path = 'assets/upload/audio/';

```
            if(!empty($data['audio_data']) && $data['data']->tstatus == 'C'){
                foreach($data['audio_data'] as $rw){
                  //print_r($file_path.$rw->audio_file_name);exit;
                  unlink(FCPATH .$file_path.$rw->audio_file_name);
                }
            }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php: see third user contributed note "unlink($fileName); failed for me .
Then i tried using the realpath($fileName)  function as
unlink(realpath($fileName)); it worked "

Comment: Is it windows server or linux server?

Comment: Make sure you have the right permissions on this folder if you are using a linux server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `base_url()` instead of `FCPATH`

**Update:-** And before this check file in the directory

```
if(file_exists($file_path.$rw->audio_file_name)){
    unlink(base_url($file_path.$rw->audio_file_name));
else{
     echo 'File does not exists';
}
```

Comment: Windows server @Sherif Salah

Comment: @SwetalinaRay your file path is accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this.

```
unlink('assets/upload/audio/'.$rw->audio_file_name);
```